# gradle build not finding executable at expected location

Tags: java, linux, gradle, build.gradle

I am new to gradle. I am getting an warning message when using gradle build:

```
gradle build
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 399ms
3 actionable tasks: 3 up-to-date
```

The build is successful, but is this an issue I should fix?

Some info:

1. usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11 only contains a src.zip file, nothing else
2. 'which java' returns /usr/bin/java
3. namei /usr/bin/java returns

```
f: /usr/bin/java
 d /
 d usr
 d bin
 l java -> /etc/alternatives/java
   d /
   d etc
   d alternatives
   l java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
     d /
     d usr
     d lib
     d jvm
     d java-11-openjdk-amd64
     d bin
     - java
```

4. echo $JAVA_HOME returns nothing
5. echo $PATH returns  `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/gradle/gradle-8.4/bin`
6. java -version returns `openjdk version "11.0.20.1" 2023-08-24 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.20.1+1-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)`
7. ChatGPT has given me a few erroneous solutions that just lead to the build failing so I won't mention those

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These warnings are expected behavior in Gradle (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/22921).

However, on Ubuntu (and Debian), they do not indicate an actual issue that needs fixing because a `src.zip -> lib/src.zip` symlink (not an executable) is intentionally placed in `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11/` when Java source code is installed with `sudo apt install openjdk-11-source` (https://askubuntu.com/questions/755853/how-to-install-jdk-sources).

In other words, Gradle thinks it might be a problem, but it isn't.

Comment: So how does one solve the error?

Comment: @KarlDjotchuangTamo It's not an error, so there's nothing to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Typically `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11` contains a JDK on Linux.

Gradle when discovering toolchains looks at such typical places where JDKs are found and warns you that you might have a corrupted JDK there that misses important files.

If I should guess, that is a left-over of a not fully uninstalled JDK. If I were you, I'd just delete that directory.